# Wireless problem after suspending my Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wireless

I have a problem, once I have resumed from suspend the wireless stops working, and I don't seem to be able to restart it again.

Comment: can any of you two see the "wlan0" entry when you type "iwconfig" into the terminal? Note: I'm still working through this issue myself. I'm getting closer to the end

Answer (score 0):

Since every time you you start or wake your computer from suspend, the wireless card is turned off... maybe it's just turned off? (That is, either configured to be disabled, or switched off with a "kill switch" on your computer.) Try to look if the wireless light is on.